Django Query calculate date with `relativedelta` error: can't adapt type 'relativedelta'
I'm facing a tricky problem and couldn't find a solution online. I hope someone here can help me figure out a "clean" way to do this.
This is my current function to retrieve all expired loans (it works):
queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
expired_loans_ids = {loan.pk for loan in queryset if loan.is_expired()}
expired_loans = queryset.filter(pk__in=expired_loans_ids)
return expired_loans

However, it's not ideal because I'm not just using a query; I must retrieve everything first. What I wanted to do was something like this:
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
expired_loans = queryset.annotate(
    expiration_date=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('timestamp') + relativedelta(months=1),
        output_field=DateField()
    )
).filter(expiration_date__lt=Now())
return expired_loans

But I get this error when using relativedelta: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'relativedelta'
It works with timedelta, but each month has a different number of days...
EDIT:
My situation is a bit more complicated, because my model include this field: rate_repeat
So the desired output would be:
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

queryset = super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
expired_loans = queryset.annotate(
    expiration_date=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('timestamp') + relativedelta(months=1) * F('rate_repeat'),
        output_field=DateField()
    )
).filter(expiration_date__lt=Now())
return expired_loans

How can I accomplish something like this?

It indeed can not, since Django needs to find an expression for this, and does not know ``relativedelta`.

It indeed can not, since Django needs to find an expression for this, and does not know relativedelta.
But it is probably not necessary anyway. We can subtract the now:
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from django.utils.timezone import now

queryset = (
    super()
    .get_queryset()
    .filter(is_active=True, timestamp__lt=now() - relativedelta(months=1))
)
or another way is to just inject the year, month and day:
from django.utils.timezone import now

y, m, d, *__ = now().timetuple()

m -= 1
if m < 1:
    m = 12
    y -= 1

queryset = (
    super()
    .get_queryset()
    .filter(
        Q(timestamp__year__lt=y)
        | Q(timestamp__year=y, timestamp__month__lt=m)
        | Q(timestamp__year=y, timestamp__month=m, timestamp__day__lt=d),
        is_active=True,
    )
)
The relative deltas are a bit complicated w.r.t. the 31st of a month for example. If you for example add a month on August, 31th, it will return September 30th, the question is if that is the expiration date.

This works, thanks!
However, my situation is a bit more complicated:
I need to multiply relativedelta(months=1) by the rate_repeat field in my model.
So the desired output would be something like this:
expired_loans = queryset.filter(timestamp__lt=now() - relativedelta(months=1) * F('rate_repeat'))
But it’s not working as expected.
I apologize for not describing the problem clearly before. I tried to simplify it as much as possible...

@zdeneklapes: can you ask a new question with the updated specs. Unfortunately this will not be very easy. As said, Django does not "understand" relativedelta, although it can be done.

@willem-van-onsem updated question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78856389/django-query-calculate-date-with-relativedelta-error-cant-adapt-type-relati
